# React/Firebase not getting doc content

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

this is my firebase test for printing the doc "week"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G145k.png

and this is my code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEDxG.png

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsPending(true);
    firestore
      .collection("Workspace")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          setError("No data");
          setIsPending(false);
        } else {
          let results = [];
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc);
          });
        }
      });
  }, []);
```

*note: firestore is imported, its actually firebase.firestore*

but the output I'm having:
`QueryDocumentSnapshot {_firestore: Firestore, _delegate: $u}`
instead of the actual list or at least their content

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: Please edit your question (by click the `edit` link right under it) to include the [minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **as text**.

Answer (score 2):

From the output is seems that you're logging a `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. Replace this

```
console.log(doc)
```

With:

```
console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_1).

Comment: Thank you so much! The tutorial that I was following wasn't explaining this! Thank you so much!

Comment: For working, up-to-date code, I always recommend using the documentation.